# Rails - setting multiple layouts for a multipart email with mailer templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

So Rails 2.2 added mailer layouts, which is great, except that I can't figure out how to make them work when I'm sending a multipart email..it's wrapping my mail content with the same layout for both the text/plain version and the text/html version. What I want is to wrap my layout around either only the text/html version, or to be able to have a separate layout for each.

Anybody encountered this? I haven't seen any mention of it elsewhere,

Cameron

Answer (score 3):

For future reference the solution in the blog post above amended in a second blog post is given below all credit to the above mentioned blog post. [Solution blog post](http://blog.kreeti.com/rails/multipart-emails-with-mailer-templates)

Add this code to your environment.rb file to stop the mailer from applying layouts to plain text emails. It also has a check that will stop it from conflicting with the exception notification plugin.

```
# Do not use the mailer layout template for plain text emails
module ActionMailer
  class Base
    private    
    def candidate_for_layout?(options)
       (!options[:file] || !options[:file].respond_to?(:content_type) ||
          options[:file].content_type != 'text/plain') &&
          !@template.send(:_exempt_from_layout?, default_template_name)
    end
  end
end
```