# Rails: How to use a partial in multipart/alternative emails (HTML and plain text)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mime, partial-views, multipart

I use a partial in various multipart emails (HTML and plain text) in Rails and have the following problem with it:

- All email "views" exist normally: both in .text.plain.erb and .text.html.erb versions
- The partial (which is located in the "shared" views folder), also exists in both versions using the required endings (as mentioned above).

The problem: In the "plain text" version of the received emails, it is the HTML partial that is rendered, not the "plain text" one.
(Everything else is rendered correctly in both versions.)

What am I probably doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch for any help with this!
Tom

Comment: I've been having this problem too - except that the multipart email renders properly in development mode, but not in production. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer that works for me. PeterD posted the following on [rails mailer with different layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652823/rails-mailer-with-different-layouts):

> ...the layouts follow a different naming scheme to the email templates. Just rename them as follows:

```
layout.text.html.erb    => layout.html.erb
layout.text.plain.erb   => layout.text.erb
```